# remove rows when it contains empty cells in r

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe(Y) that contains empty cells ->  "" or NaN or even N/A
I tried to empty the dataframe with the following command:

```
Y <- na.omit(mutate_all(Y, ~ifelse(. %in% c("N/A", "null", ""),  NA, .)))
```

But somehow this converts all values to integer (even the non numeric columns).

I can't share the dataframe or parts of it due to confidentiality, but please let me know if this problem sounds familiair and how you managed to solve it.

Comment: You could create a small reproducible data.frame that best describes your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you could use:

```
type.convert(data.frame(gsub('^N/A$', '', trimws(as.matrix(Y))))
```

Note that `type.convert(c('', 'NaN', 'NA', 8, 9))` will convert the vector to numeric. the only issue is the `N/A` string

Comment: this followed by the na.omit() command worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have factors in your data which is causing the trouble. You can apply the function to only character and factor columns in the data.

```
library(dplyr) #dplyr > 1.0.0

Y %>%
  mutate(across(where(~is.character(.) | is.factor(.)), 
                ~as.character(ifelse(. %in% c("N/A", "null", ""),  NA, .)))) %>%
  na.omit() -> Y
```